# Handling in Excel

Tags: excel

I got this calculated incremental column

10

12

14

20

25

I have a input value let say: 15

Now, because 15 is exceding 14 in this case the output value that I want is 14.

How do achieve this in Excel formula? Excel is not really my think so if you could guide me that will be good.

Thanks

Comment: i think you'll need to add a lot more detail to not get this question closed as off-topic.  how is your data laid out?  where are you putting the new value?  where did the calculated values come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try =SMALL($A$2:$A$6,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,"<="&C2))
where your values (10 12 14...) are stored in A2:A6 and C2 contains 15. works for me

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you need can be done using a `VLOOKUP` formula. You haven't defined what should happen with an input value smaller than the first value in your list (e.g. an input value of 8). VLOOKUP will return the `#N/A` error value for that which may/may not be the behaviour you need.

Anyway, assuming that:

- your list is in A1:A5
- your list is in ascending order
- your input value is in C1

the formula you need would be

`=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:A5,1,TRUE)`

The input value and list to search are obvious. The `1` specifies to return a value from the 1st column (obvious as you only have one column) and `TRUE` specifies that you want to return the largest value that is less than or equal to the input value (`FALSE` would specify an exact match only, `TRUE` is the default and could thus be omitted)

There's more info about `VLOOKUP` on the Microsoft Office site [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)